# Find pathname from dlopen handle on OSX

Tags: c, macos, dyld

I have `dlopen()`'ed a library, and I want to invert back from the handle it passes to me to the full pathname of shared library.  On Linux and friends, I know that I can use `dlinfo()` to get the linkmap and iterate through those structures, but I can't seem to find an analogue on OSX.  The closest thing I can do is to either:

- Use `dyld_image_count()` and `dyld_get_image_name()`, iterate over all the currently opened libraries and hope I can guess which one corresponds to my handle
- Somehow find a symbol that lives inside of the handle I have, and pass that to `dladdr()`.

If I have apriori knowledge as to a symbol name inside of the library I just opened, I can `dlsym()` that and then use `dladdr()`.  That works fine.  But in the general case where I have no idea what is inside this shared library, I would need to be able to enumerate symbols to do that, which I don't know how to do either.

So any tips on how to lookup the pathname of a library from its `dlopen` handle would be very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes there isn't an analog. Mind you reading the [source from here](https://code.google.com/p/toolwhip/source/browse/trunk/cctools/libdyld/dlopen.c) it looks like a trivial reverse-assemble

Comment: The current dlfcn API implementation is very different from the Toolwhip implementation. See [dyldAPIs.cpp](http://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-239.3/src/dyldAPIs.cpp) from OS X 10.9.

Comment: Thank you for your posts!  I believe that source holds the answer for me, but I have something of a silly question; If the return value from `dlopen()` is an `ImageLoader` subclass, but that source is not available in the standard library, is there a better way to get at the internal data than just including that source in my project?  As far as I can tell, the data returned to me from `dlopen()` is completely opaque and Apple doesn't provide any methods to edit it.  Should I just copy Apple's source into my own and call it good?

Comment: Note: In general, on Unix, an open file handle may reference an underlying inode that has no links to it. It's a perfectly normal occurrence. Just be prepared to deal with it.

Comment: @KubaOber would that be the case when I have opened a file, deleted the file from the shell and then try to look up the file path from the application that previously opened it?

Comment: @staticfloat: Exactly!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After about a year of using the solution provided by 0xced, we discovered an alternative method that is simpler and avoids one (rather rare) failure mode; specifically, because 0xced's code snippet iterates through each dylib currently loaded, finds the first exported symbol, attempts to resolve it in the dylib currently being sought, and returns positive if that symbol is found in that particular dylib, you can have false positives if the first exported symbol from an arbitrary library happens to be present inside of the dylib you're currently searching for.

My solution was to use `_dyld_get_image_name(i)` to get the absolute path of each image loaded, `dlopen()` that image, and compare the handle (after masking out any mode bits set by `dlopen()` due to usage of things like `RTLD_FIRST`) to ensure that this dylib is actually the same file as the handle passed into my function.

The complete function [can be seen here](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/0027ed143e90d0f965694de7ea8c692d75ffa1a5/src/sys.c#L572-L583), as a part of the Julia Language, with the relevant portion copied below:

```
// Iterate through all images currently in memory
for (int32_t i = _dyld_image_count(); i >= 0 ; i--) {
    // dlopen() each image, check handle
    const char *image_name = _dyld_get_image_name(i);
    uv_lib_t *probe_lib = jl_load_dynamic_library(image_name, JL_RTLD_DEFAULT);
    void *probe_handle = probe_lib->handle;
    uv_dlclose(probe_lib);

    // If the handle is the same as what was passed in (modulo mode bits), return this image name
    if (((intptr_t)handle & (-4)) == ((intptr_t)probe_handle & (-4)))
        return image_name;
}
```

Note that functions such as `jl_load_dynamic_library()` are wrappers around `dlopen()` that return `libuv` types, but the spirit of the code remains the same.

Answer (score 20):

Here is how you can get the absolute path of a handle returned by `dlopen`.

1. In order to get the absolute path, you need to call the `dladdr` function and retrieve the `Dl_info.dli_fname` field.
2. In order to call the `dladdr` function, you need to give it an address.
3. In order to get an address given a handle, you have to call the `dlsym` function with a symbol.
4. In order to get a symbol out of a loaded library, you have to parse the library to find its symbol table and iterate over the symbols. You need to find an external symbol because `dlsym` only searches for external symbols.

Put it all together and you get this:

```
#import <dlfcn.h>
#import <mach-o/dyld.h>
#import <mach-o/nlist.h>
#import <stdio.h>
#import <string.h>

#ifdef __LP64__
typedef struct mach_header_64 mach_header_t;
typedef struct segment_command_64 segment_command_t;
typedef struct nlist_64 nlist_t;
#else
typedef struct mach_header mach_header_t;
typedef struct segment_command segment_command_t;
typedef struct nlist nlist_t;
#endif

static const char * first_external_symbol_for_image(const mach_header_t *header)
{
    Dl_info info;
    if (dladdr(header, &info) == 0)
        return NULL;

    segment_command_t *seg_linkedit = NULL;
    segment_command_t *seg_text = NULL;
    struct symtab_command *symtab = NULL;

    struct load_command *cmd = (struct load_command *)((intptr_t)header + sizeof(mach_header_t));
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < header->ncmds; i++, cmd = (struct load_command *)((intptr_t)cmd + cmd->cmdsize))
    {
        switch(cmd->cmd)
        {
            case LC_SEGMENT:
            case LC_SEGMENT_64:
                if (!strcmp(((segment_command_t *)cmd)->segname, SEG_TEXT))
                    seg_text = (segment_command_t *)cmd;
                else if (!strcmp(((segment_command_t *)cmd)->segname, SEG_LINKEDIT))
                    seg_linkedit = (segment_command_t *)cmd;
                break;

            case LC_SYMTAB:
                symtab = (struct symtab_command *)cmd;
                break;
        }
    }

    if ((seg_text == NULL) || (seg_linkedit == NULL) || (symtab == NULL))
        return NULL;

    intptr_t file_slide = ((intptr_t)seg_linkedit->vmaddr - (intptr_t)seg_text->vmaddr) - seg_linkedit->fileoff;
    intptr_t strings = (intptr_t)header + (symtab->stroff + file_slide);
    nlist_t *sym = (nlist_t *)((intptr_t)header + (symtab->symoff + file_slide));

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < symtab->nsyms; i++, sym++)
    {
        if ((sym->n_type & N_EXT) != N_EXT || !sym->n_value)
            continue;

        return (const char *)strings + sym->n_un.n_strx;
    }

    return NULL;
}

const char * pathname_for_handle(void *handle)
{
    for (int32_t i = _dyld_image_count(); i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        const char *first_symbol = first_external_symbol_for_image((const mach_header_t *)_dyld_get_image_header(i));
        if (first_symbol && strlen(first_symbol) > 1)
        {
            handle = (void *)((intptr_t)handle | 1); // in order to trigger findExportedSymbol instead of findExportedSymbolInImageOrDependentImages. See `dlsym` implementation at http://opensource.apple.com/source/dyld/dyld-239.3/src/dyldAPIs.cpp
            first_symbol++; // in order to remove the leading underscore
            void *address = dlsym(handle, first_symbol);
            Dl_info info;
            if (dladdr(address, &info))
                return info.dli_fname;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    void *libxml2 = dlopen("libxml2.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    printf("libxml2 path: %s\n", pathname_for_handle(libxml2));
    dlclose(libxml2);
    return 0;
}
```

If you run this code, it will yield the expected result: `libxml2 path: /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib`

Comment: Fantastic code, thank you so much for putting this together.  I had thought of pulling out the `load_command` structures, but stubbornly thought there must have been an easier way.  After seeing it broken down like this, I see it's actually not so bad!  Thank you again!

Comment: We ran into a problem with this solution regarding multiple libraries having the same first exported symbol!  We came up with a simpler, more robust solution below.  Thanks again for setting me on the right track for all this time though!