# What causes segmentation fault in program to dump Mach-O symbols?

Tags: c, macos, dyld, mach-o

I wrote the below program to dump symbols of a Mach-O file. (I realise this is duplicating existing commands like `nm`, but I wanted to do it myself in order to learn. Note I could `mmap` it myself but for various reasons I wanted to let `dyld` load it into memory for me.)

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <mach-o/dyld.h>
#include <mach-o/nlist.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef MH_DYLIB_IN_CACHE
#       define MH_DYLIB_IN_CACHE 0x80000000
#endif

#define DYLD_MASKREMOVE(_handle) (((intptr_t)(_handle) & (-4)))

static const struct mach_header* dyld2hdr(void *handle) {
        uint32_t count = _dyld_image_count();
        for (uint32_t index = 0; index < count; index++) {
                const char *dll = _dyld_get_image_name(index);
                void *h2 = dlopen(dll, RTLD_LOCAL | RTLD_LAZY);
                assert(h2 != NULL);
                if (DYLD_MASKREMOVE(handle) == DYLD_MASKREMOVE(h2)) {
                    int rc = dlclose(h2);
                    assert(rc == 0);
                    return _dyld_get_image_header(index);
                }
                int rc = dlclose(h2);
                assert(rc == 0);
        }
        abort(); // Shouldn't be reached
}

const struct load_command* findLoadCmd(const struct mach_header_64* header64, uint32_t cmd) {
        const char *ptr = ((void*)header64) + sizeof(struct mach_header_64);
        for (uint32_t j = 0; j < header64->ncmds; j++) {
                const struct load_command *lc = (const struct load_command *)ptr;
                ptr += lc->cmdsize;
                if (lc->cmd == cmd)
                        return lc;
        }
        return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
        if (argc != 2) {
                fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: wrong arguments\n");
                return 1;
        }
        const char* imageName = argv[1];
        void *dl = dlopen(imageName, RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_LOCAL);
        if (dl == NULL) {
                fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror()); 
                return 1;
        }
        const struct mach_header* hdr = dyld2hdr(dl);
        struct mach_header_64* hdr64 = (struct mach_header_64*)hdr;
        if ((hdr64->flags & MH_DYLIB_IN_CACHE) != 0) {
                fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: image '%s' is in the dylib cache, which is not supported by this tool\n",imageName);
                return 1;
        }
        const struct symtab_command* symtab = (const struct symtab_command*)findLoadCmd(hdr64, LC_SYMTAB);
        assert(symtab != NULL);
        struct nlist_64 *syms = ((void*)hdr64) + (int64_t)(symtab->symoff); 
        char *strtab = (((void*)hdr64) + (int64_t)(symtab->stroff));
        int count = 0;
        for (uint32_t symidx = 0; symidx < symtab->nsyms; symidx++) {
                uint32_t strx = syms[symidx].n_un.n_strx;
                if (strx == 0)
                        continue;
                char * symName = &(strtab[strx]);
                if (symName[0] != '_')
                    continue;
                symName++;
                void *found = dlsym(dl,symName);
                if (found == NULL)
                    continue;
                printf("SYMBOL: %s\n", symName);
                count++;
        }
        printf("Symbols found = %d\n", count);
        int closeRC = dlclose(dl);
        assert(closeRC == 0);
        return 0;
}
```

Run it on itself, it works:

```
clang -DNDEBUG -g -o symdump symdump.c
./symdump symdump
```

And run it on a bunch of other random executables, e.g. `/bin/ls`, it works for them too. ("Works" meaning it outputs some symbols and completes successfully without crashing; whether it is outputting the right ones is outside the scope of this question.) But, run it on `/usr/bin/sqlite3`, and it segfaults reading the symbol name. What is different about that executable which makes that one fail but other ones like `/bin/ls` work?

(Acknowledgement: the `dyld2hdr` function to convert dyld handle to Mach-O header was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30293362).)

(If relevant, testing on macOS 10.14.6 and using compiler `Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)`.)

I don't agree this is a duplicate of [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65248584/), because the solution to that was to use the `dyld_cache_mapping_info` structure to convert file offsets to memory offsets for dyld shared cache images; that solution isn't relevant here, because the `sqlite3` executable is not part of the dyld shared cache.

Comment: Use a debugger. It will tell you immediately which line of code triggers the seg fault. Can also use it to step thru the code and see precisely what condition causes the problem.

Comment: @kaylum I tried using lldb. It gets confused about having two executables loaded, and it doesn't work. But I can tell from the crash report that the segfault happens on the line `if (symName[0] != '_')`. What I don't understand is why `symName` doesn't point to a valid address. It seems to be pointing past the end of sqlite3's `__LINKEDIT` section when it should be pointing inside it.

Comment: Voting to close this as a duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65263569/2302862). `stroff` is _still_ a file offset, not a memory one.

Comment: @Siguza the solution to my previous question was to use the `dyld_cache_mapping_info` structure to convert file offsets to memory offsets. That solution only works for images in the dyld shared cache. `/usr/bin/sqlite3`, being an executable, is not in the dyld shared cache, so the same approach doesn't work here. Is there a similar mapping info structure for non-shared cache images?

Comment: @SimonKissane Yes, the `LC_SEGMENT_64` load commands in the Mach-O header.

Comment: @kaylum I worked out how to unconfuse lldb. Use lipo to extract one architecture from sqlite3, `codesign --remove-signature`, then use a hex editor to change the 13th byte of the file from 0x02 (`MH_EXECUTE`) to 0x06 (`MH_DYLIB`) – then lldb gets confused no more

Comment: @Siguza Thanks, that worked: `const struct nlist_64 *syms = (const struct nlist_64 *)(segcmd->vmaddr + (symtab->symoff - segcmd->fileoff) + slide);
        const char *strtab = (const char *)(segcmd->vmaddr + (symtab->stroff - segcmd->fileoff) + slide);` where `segcmd` is the `__LINKEDIT` segment and `slide` is the return value of `_dyld_get_image_vmaddr_slide`. It even works for the dyld shared cache image, instead of parsing `dyld_cache_mapping_info` for them